# OpenRefine - error says I need to use API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs

Tags: openrefine

I am an absolute beginner, I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGVtycv3SS0) video guide, and try to fetch data from google maps as described between 1:10:10 and 1:13:05. However in the last passage I get this error:

```
{
   "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

This image shows what I should get instead (see column "geolocation")

[image]

I am not a company or anything, is there any way to get this done for free?

Answer (score 0):

As it says on the page at http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account you have to register for a billing account, but once you have done that, you get $200 of free requests each month (which https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/ suggests is about 40,000 calls) - so as long as your usage is not over that, there is no charge for this.

There are alternative services that support geocoding, and as long as you can make a request to the service using a URL you can use them in OpenRefine in the same was as is described in that video. Just as an example, one option might be the Nominatim service that works with OpenStreetMap - documentation at https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Search/ - but you will have to modify the URL you create in the 'geoloc' column (at 1:11:16) to be more like:

```
   "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="+value+"&format=json"
```

And the parsing of the returned JSON will change to match the JSON being returned by Nominatim (documented at https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Output/)

Comment: Thank you. Is this "new"? the guy in the 2017 video seems to be able to do this without any personal key

Comment: @Nik yes - this change happened in June 2018 - see https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/